# Stata: rename variables in lowercase when importing from Excel

Tags: excel, variables, import, stata

I'm trying to import an Excel sheet that has variable names which have a mix of uppercase and lowercase letters.  I want Stata to read them all as lower case but when I put the `case(lower)` option in, Stata returns `option case() not allowed`.

Here is what I try to put in:

```
import excel "/Users/p/D/B/File name/", sheet("Sheet1") firstrow case(lower)
```

The `import` command works fine when I don't use the `case()` option. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your file name actually end with a forward slash? I have never seen this. What Stata release are you using? Import excel is a new thing. It looks also like you are using a Mac? So many aspects to the question. Otherwise, first thing to do would be to turn on trace and look at precisely where the error is happening. Or post your file and the real code that is and isn't working for you, and we can help better.

Comment: You have not given us a reproducible example and no-one trying independently has been able to devise one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it difficult to reproduce your problem, but below is a working example using various `case()` options (basically from `help import excel`):

```
clear all
set more off


*----------------- Create data -----------------------------

* Load example Stata data base
sysuse auto
keep make price headroom length turn

* Change variable names to experiment
rename (headroom length turn) (HEADRoom LENGTH turN)

* Create example Excel file
export excel auto, firstrow(variables) replace


*----------------- Importing -------------------------------

* Import just as it is
import excel auto.xls, firstrow clear
describe

* Import with upper case
import excel auto.xls, firstrow case(upper) clear
describe

* Import with lower case
import excel auto.xls, firstrow case(lower) clear
describe
```

Note they all work fine. Variable **names** are converted to upper/lower case accordingly. Variable **labels** are not, but this is expected. From `help import excel` we have:

> The original names in the first row are stored unmodified as variable
>   labels.

and `case()` *only* affects variable names.

You also mention:

> The import command works fine when I don't use the `case()` option.

Suppose this is true. Then to convert variable names to lower case after the import, you can try

```
rename _all, lower
```

See `help rename group` for details. (But like I showed, the `case()` option works.)

Finally, if it is the variable **labels** you are after, you can change them using something like

```
foreach varr of varlist _all {
    label variable `varr' "`varr'"
}
```

That just copies the variable name to the label, for all variables. So running that after all your variable names are converted to lower case, would give you variable labels that are also lower case. Run `help label` for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roberto Ferrer . Yes for some reason when I include the case() option in my stata (stata 12se on a mac) it reads (case option not allowed). Anyway, when I use the rename _all,lower command it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I tried creating your example data just as you did but again stata said option case() not allowed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error [r(198) "option case() not allowed"] when attempting to run the following code intended to import only a subset of columns from an excel file:

```
import excel var1 var2 var3 using "excel_file.xlsx", firstrow case(lower) sheet("SHEET") clear
```

BUT the command worked fine when I DID NOT list the subset of variables required from the excel file:

```
import excel using "excel_file.xlsx", firstrow case(lower) sheet("SHEET") clear
```

Perhaps this example applies to your original problem.

Comment: No examples in the original question or the accepted answer specified variable names.  It seems that you're trying something different.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).